# Excel formula for declining number, in 5 year intervals

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a starting number that declines 6% each year. I’d like to show intervals of the number, for every 5 years (but it still declines 6% every year, not just every 5 years). I did a simple Excel equation =SUM(H5-(Annual_Reduction*H5))    that reduced the previous number by 6%, and it went on and on, and looked sloppy. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is what I used, where H5 is the previous cell, and Annual_Reduction was .06  and I copied the formula for 80 cells.
=SUM(H5-(Annual_Reduction*H5))

For example, let's say I have a starting number of 100,000 in year 2020. It declines 6% each year. Ideally, I'd like to see what the number is for years 2025, 2030, 2035, 2040, and so on for every 5 years until it reaches zero, or perhaps just for say 100 years.

Comment: Please add some sample data and include an example of what you would like to work out, your question is not clear enough to give an answer as it is. Please EDIT your question with the sample data, do not add it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 year depreciated growth at -6% (0.94):

```
=ROUND(A1*POWER(0.94,5),2)
```

The rounding will damage your long term values.  Either take it off and show the cell as currency at 2 decimal places, or reference the original cell ($A$1) and increase the numeral 5 to whatever year you want calculated.

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Thank you Brian! And thanks Kevin for making sure the question was more clear.