# Excel formula for cumulative costs in 5 year increments

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I had a previous problem that was solved that was similar, but wasn’t a running total: 
[Excel formula for declining number, in 5 year intervals](https://superuser.com/questions/1391329/excel-formula-for-declining-number-in-5-year-intervals)

So this number is about budge forecasting. It needs to include the average annual inflation rate. The parts that are tricky for me, is that I need it to be in 5 year increments and it needs to be cumulative (meaning, it keeps adding the previous amounts with the current year).

For example, let’s say in 2020 the budget is $100. Average annual inflation rate is 3%. In 2021, the budget is $113. That running total in 2005 is 531 (so that means years 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024 is 100, 103, 106, 109, and 113 respectfully. So how would I create a repeating formula that tabulates like this  that only shows every 5 years (in other words, I don’t want 5 rows, just one for every 5 year increment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence of nominal (ie after inflation ) payments is a "geometric sequence" or "geometric progression". The nth term in the sequence:

[image]

where `a` is the initial value, r is the common ratio.

In your example `a = 100`, `r = 1 + 0.03`

You want to calculated the sum of the sequence after n years or the "geometric series". The nth item in the series is calculated by:

[image]

Below is a minimal example:

[image]

You can remove the years 2 - 4 from the spreadheet since the formula in each column is independent of the previous one.

More on geometric sequence and series on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)

Answer (score 3):

The basic formula is `start_amount * (1 + inf_rate)^years`
where:

- `start_amount` is the the original dollar amount - eg $1,000,000
- `inf_rate` is the annual inflation rate as a decimal  - eg 0.03
- `years` is the number of years since the start - eg 0, 5, 10, etc

Here's a minimal example.
[image: simple spreadsheet calculating future value in multi year increments]

Note Use of absolute references for all but the current year means you can copy the formula from one column to the next.

There's a built in function for calculating future value `FV` that does basically the same thing but also allows for regular payments as in a loan or annuity.

Comment: Hi David. After reading your answer, I realized my questions wasn't very clear. I've updated it to make it more clear about the need for cumulative running total.

Comment: Yes @devhead that is quite a different question now after your edits.  I'll add a new answer rather than edit this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an *array formula* to get the job done where A3 holds your base amount:

```
=SERIESSUM(1.03,1,1,INDEX((A3*ROW(1:5))/ROW(1:5),))
```

Note with array forumlas you must press cntrl+shift+enter after typing or pasting it in or after any changes.

Change the numeral 5 to be whatever amount of years you need.

Here is a way without array formulas but you must enter 100 (or your base amount) for each year you want calculated.

For 5 years:

```
=SERIESSUM(1.03,1,1,{100,100,100,100,100})
```

For 10 years:

```
=SERIESSUM(1.03,1,1,{100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100})
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe I'm just not clear. The number over 5 years should be at least 5x the origal number, as it's cumulative - that is, the running amount of the entire annual amount. So in other words,  I want to see how much the company paid over the course of 5 years.

Comment: Still not what I'm looking for. Hopefully ths image is worth a thousand words https://imgur.com/a/sdOjwGW

Comment: @devhead okay first year does have interest, I stripped the +100 off the end.  It looks like every fourth year has $4 instead of $3.  Is the actual interest rate 3.3%?

Comment: Looks much better. However, when I do the basic formula that lists every year, then I add it up, its different than your formula. So with yours (I'm using your exact formula), on 5th year, it's $545; 10th year it's $1,165. On mine, on 5th year, it's $547; 10th year it's $1,181.

Comment: @devhead Yes on your chart why does every 4th year add $4 instead of $3?  And when I total your 10 amounts it comes to 1180 instead or 1181.

Comment: here is my excel file i'm using: https://ufile.io/emyfc

Comment: @devhead fixed*

Comment: Brian. thank you for your help. This still doesn't work. I can't put any more time into this task. Thanks.

Comment: @devhead okay no problem, sorry we couldn't get it sorted for you.

Comment: Based upon the Image shared by @devhead, this could be achieved using Future Value formula, (I think). See this for example: `=FV(3.3%,5,-103)`. In this formula, the first argument `3.3%` is the rate of growth, second argument `5` is the number of periods, and last argument `-103` is the payment amount. This evaluates to 550. Similarly, for 10 years `=FV(3.3%,10,-103)` evaluates 1197.22.